# Decoupled MI Provider in C#

Tags: c#, wmi, cim

So I've inherited three Windows NT-Services written in C#. One of the tasks now is to add WMI-data so the status of the NT-Service can be tracked in our monitoring software.

Searching the internet doesn't provide me with any samples how to create a Decoupled MI Provider in .Net (4.7)? I got a lot of old examples to the WMI (v1) however. But that technology isn't advised to use anymore by Microsoft. Also I can't really find the correct terminology for this, I've seen MI, MMI, WMIv2 and CIM, CIMv2, WMI.Net 2.0 Provider Extensions...

I'm not looking for the namespace System.Management.(Instrumentation), but for the [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.management.infrastructure(v=vs.85).aspx).
The [examples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Management-Infrastructure-79fb414f) [from](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Server-manager-deployment-3cbfd7e8) Microsoft are either in C++ and not C# Providers.

Any help in samples is greatly appreciated!